# Is Parse the right choice if your app does not need Facebook integration?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to build something similar to a poll service for mobile but it doesn't need Facebook.

- After Facebook's acqusition, is Parse.com still a viable option if your web app does not need Facebook integration? Could app developers (customers) log in to my backend without a Facebook account?
- Is it possible to build premium features with Parse and then charge for them?
- Do you own your data when using Parse.com? I.e., can you export it in case you decide to move to another service in the future?

I am hoping someone with experience can shed some light on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After Facebook's acqusition, is Parse.com still a viable option if
>   your web app does not need Facebook integration? Could app developers
>   (customers) log in to my backend without a Facebook account?

yes,for now.

> Is it possible to build premium features with Parse and then charge
>   for them?

yes

> Do you own your data when using Parse.com? I.e., can you export it in
>   case you decide to move to another service in the future?

yes

I'd suggest you always have a backup plan,when using a BAAS.I pity Stackmob users that didnt.You dont know if parse will still be there in 3 years or their features and pricing will change.Never rely on a BAAS on the long run.

Comment: Thank you very much. To clarify, does Parse.com offer login and authentication functionality (as opposed to building this yourself on Parse) if you don't want to have your customers (the developers using the poll platform built on Parse) have to log in with their Facebook accounts? And do they offer payment services as well or do you have to do that manually using something like PayPal integration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes parse has standalone login features with username, and password, in addition to twitter, and facebook. They even handle lost password reset's via email as long as the user has the email field entered. You can check if the user's email has been verified via the emailVerified field.

I'm using stripe.com's payment system via parse's cloud code. I will admit this is not a complete drop in feature for parse yet, but maybe in the future. stripe is made for developers, and I find it to be a very powerful payment system. I can answer some basic stripe/parse questions as I have written myself basically a semi-complete API for handling customers, card, and charges.